# How to use CSS to make block center or take up full width

Tags: css, css-float

I have a lot of small sections generate via php. They are different sizes. I want though that there is a text button on the bottom that will take up the full width.

I first had
display: block;
    float: left;

But it was to much to the left, I then tried:
 display: inline-block

But it was too small and there was extra space on either side. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fDvC.jpg) is a screenshot of it with the extra space. Any suggestions? I am working on the buy now button.

PHP Generate code
    
    global $wpdb;
    $cat= $_POST['cat'];
    if($cat=='All')
    {
        $items = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'afp_items  ORDER BY item_id ASC');
        }else
    {
        $items = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'afp_items WHERE item_category="'.$cat.'" ORDER BY item_id ASC');
    }
    $output='';

```
$k = 1;
        foreach ($items as $item ){
                $output.='<div class="afp-single-item">
                <img alt="" class="img-link-initial" src="' . $item->item_thumbnail . '">
                <div class="item-overlay" style="display: none;">
                      <img src="' . $item->item_thumbnail . '" width="101%">
                           <div class="wishlist-details">';
                           if($item->item_title != null) { $output.='<h2>' . $item->item_title . '</h2>'; }

                          $output.='
                                    <span>Share This</span>


                                </div>
                                     ';


                    if($item->item_link != null) { $output.='<a target="_blank" class="buynow" href="' . $item->item_link . '">Buy Now</a>
                    '; }
                $output.='
                            </div>

            </div>';

            $k++;
        }
    $output.='</div><div class="afp-clear"></div>'; 


        echo $output;
```

Template code:

```
<?php

/**

 * Template Name: Shop Page Template

 *

 */



get_header(); ?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=54330784694";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>



<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/isotop.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.isotope.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div id="show_wrap">

<div class="section-header" >

    <h2>SHOP</h2>

</div>



<?php

    global $wpdb;

        //Get The Plugin Options

    $afpOptions = get_option('afpOptions'); 



    //SQL Queries

    switch( $afpOptions['sort_items'] ){

        case 'title':

        $orderby = 'item_title ASC';

        break;

        case 'date':

        $orderby = 'item_date DESC';

        break;

        case 'client':

        $orderby = 'item_title ASC';

        break;

        case 'id':

        $orderby = 'item_id ASC';

        break;

    }

    $items = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'afp_items ORDER BY ' . $orderby);

    if( $afpOptions['sort_cat'] == 'on' ){

        $orderby = ' ORDER BY cat_name';

    } else {

        $orderby = '';

    }

    $cats = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'afp_categories' . $orderby);



    ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="portfolioFilter">
        <?php
            //AFP Main Container
            echo '<a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All</a>';
            foreach ( $cats as $cat ){
                    echo '<a href="#" data-filter=".' . ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $cat->cat_name) . '">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolioContainer" style="padding-bottom:250px;">
            <?php foreach ($items as $item ){ ?>
                <div class="<?php echo ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $item->item_category); ?>">
                    <img alt="" class="img-link-initial" src="<?php echo $item->item_thumbnail; ?>">
                    <div class="item-overlay" style="display: none;">
                          <img src="<?php echo $item->item_thumbnail; ?>" width="101%">
                               <div class="wishlist-details">

                                    <?php  if($item->item_title != null) {?>
                                    <h2><?php echo $item->item_title; ?></h2> 
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <p class="share_this">Share This</p> 
                                    <div class="shop_bottom_border_0ld">&nbsp;</div> 
                                    <p class="social_share_box"> 
                                    <div class="share_icon_only fleft"><div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo $item->item_link; ?>" data-type="button"></div></div>
                                    <div class="share_icon_only fleft"><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo $item->item_link; ?>" data-count="none">Tweet</a></div> 
                                    <div class="share_icon_only fleft" style="width:40px;">
                                    <a  target="_blank" href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='<?php echo $item->item_link;?>&media=<?php echo $item->item_thumbnail; ?>&description=<?php echo $item->item_title; ?>"
                                    data-pin-do="buttonPin"
                                    data-pin-config="above">
                                    <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
                                    </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear"></div> 
                                    </p><br />

                                    <?php if($item->item_link != null) { ?>
                                        <p><a target="_blank" class="buynow" href="<?php echo $item->item_link; ?>">Buy Now</a></p>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="afp-clear clear20"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function(){
    var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
    });

    $('.portfolioFilter a').click(function(){
        $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
         });
         return false;
    }); 
});

</script>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And the CSS

```
.buynow {
    background-color: #F5D2D5;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left; 
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 42px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 230px;
}

.shop_bottom_border{
    border-bottom:1px solid  #CCC;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the necessary code or a jsfiddle that isolates the problem so we can help you?

Comment: Like @JoshPowell said, you should post some code.  It will really help clear some things up.  Also, `block` elements take up the maximum width by default, adding a float will push them to one side and minimize them to make room for other elements.

Comment: How is the best way for me to put the php and css code?